# Data-binding function parameter within ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to bind the value of `cat` to the `(click)` function parameter and understandably getting an error. Is there a way I can do this without looping a parent element of the `<button>`?

```
<button type="button" (click)="UpdateCategoryFilter({{cat}})" *ngFor="let cat of categories">
        {{cat}}
</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never combine `[...]` or `(...)` with `{{...}}` either one or the other, but not both at the same time

It should be

```
 (click)="UpdateCategoryFilter(cat)"
```

`{{...}}` is also only for string interpolation. Values bound this way will always be strings, while `[foo]="someValue"` will pass `someValue` with the original type if `foo` is a property.

Comment: Ok thanks, I didn't know that! Besides the variable type - would doing `onclick="foo({{cat}})"` have roughly the same functionality?

Comment: It would add a property `onclick="foo(stringValueOfCat)"`, but this way the browser would try to call `window.foo(stringValueOfCat)"` which would probably be far from what you want (`onclick` is handled by the browser directly without Angular). First there is probably no `window.foo` and also no `window.stringValueOfCat`. `on-click="foo('{{cat}}')"` might do what you want if you insist on `{{...}}`. See also https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax

Comment: @Reed Binding to event property `onclick`(like `onclick="foo({{cat}})"`) is disallowed for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

In html, the code you write in between the quotation marks of an event (such as `(click)`) is a pure typescript/js code, and as you would not write {{cat}} in your typescript code, you shouldn't write it in the place you wrote it.
Imagine that what you just tried to do is replacing the `cat` with it's code value, and then executing the code `UpdateCatagoryFilter(x)`, where `x` is cat's value, and you try to use it as a variable name. 
The meaning of `(event)="..."` syntax is: when an event `event` is emitted, execute the code `...`.